# Premake5 'command not found' when trying to make Xcode file

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, installation, premake

There has been one question asked like this two years ago however the answer given to that question hasn't fixed the issue I am having.

/Documents/Unreal\ Projects/Voxel_Terrain/Thirdparty/accidental-noise-library/premake5 ; exit;
Type 'premake5 --help' for help

logout
Saving session...

...copying shared history...

...saving history...truncating history files...

...completed.

[Process completed]

This is the output I get when I run the premake executable however when I try to run a command such as 'premake5 --help' in the terminal, I receive a 'command not found error.

Premake is located in the correct folder. Any idea`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are running on macOS, you would have to do:

```
$ cd folder_containing_premake
$ ./premake5 --help
```

The `./` is required to execute a local file. Alternatively, you can [add the folder containing Premake to your path](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176786/how-to-add-mysql-to-path-variable-to-resolve-mysql-command-not-found).

Comment: Ah so the ./ is needed before it.